# Why can't I add more than one set of object entries when using onload in image pre loader? (runnable code included)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

There is something wrong with my preloader. I want to:

- have an array of objects that have a key for the image name, and then the url for the image as the value
- create each image object one by one, and then when it is loaded push that into an object that has the name as the key and the actual image object as the value.

I have been working on it all day, and it nearly works. The problem is I can't seem to have more than one object in my `images` object at a time!

Is this whole idea wrong? I need the images preloaded and accessible for the game. I will add a function to start the game once they are all loaded later, but for now I am stuck. I searched all day for other peoples solutions, and they all seem to relate to loading images into the browser cache rather than having them ready to draw using `ctx.drawImage` or they are totally over engineered with many multiple layers of callbacks and unwanted functionality.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let images = {};

function preloadImages(arrayOfNames) {
  const img = new Image();

  for (let value of arrayOfNames) {
    for (let key in value) {
      let name = key;
      img.src = value[key];

      console.log(name); // alerts key
      console.log(img.src); // alerts key's value
      
      img.onload = function addToImagesObject() {
        images[name] = img; // WHY does the tweet overwrite the zombie and not just add to the images so we have 2 entries?
        ctx.drawImage(images[name], 0, 0);
        console.log(images);
      };
    }
  }
}

const arrayOfNames = [
  { zombie: 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x100' },
  { tweet: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150' },
];

preloadImages(arrayOfNames);
```

```html
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="650" height="650">Sorry, your browser can't display
    canvas
  </canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same Image object for your loops. That means each iteration you are overwriting the src and the onload function of that same object. So the last iteration is the one that is going to be used.

So your "tweet" property isn't overwriting your "zombie" one. The zombie one never existed, because it was never created in the first place. The onload function that would have created it never ran as it was overwritten before the browser had time to load the image and call it.

Simply use a different image object in each loop iteration. This will make it so you have separate images and event calls for each value.

```
for (let key in value) {
  const img = new Image();
```

---

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let images = {};

function preloadImages(arrayOfNames) {
  for (let value of arrayOfNames) {
    for (let key in value) {
      //each value should get it's own image object
      const img = new Image();
      let name = key;
      img.src = value[key];

      console.log(name); // alerts key
      console.log(img.src); // alerts key's value
      
      img.onload = function addToImagesObject() {
        images[name] = img; // WHY does the tweet overwrite the zombie and not just add to the images so we have 2 entries?
        ctx.drawImage(images[name], 0, 0);
        console.log(images);
      };
    }
  }
}

const arrayOfNames = [
  { zombie: 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x100' },
  { tweet: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150' },
];

preloadImages(arrayOfNames);
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="650" height="650">Sorry, your browser can't display
    canvas
  </canvas>
```